# phpMyAdmin - Error You should upgrade to MySQL 5.5.0 or later

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, upgrade, require

I installed phpMyAdmin-4.2.9.1-english on a Centos 6.5 platform.

> 2.6.32-431.23.3.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jul 31 17:20:51 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

When I login I get the following screen:

```
phpMyAdmin - Error

You should upgrade to MySQL 5.5.0 or later.
```

---

I am using Server version: 5.1.73

What should I do?

Comment: No offense, but the solution would appear to be pretty cut and dry. Upgrade your MySQL version or don't use PHPMyAdmin. I'm sure you could use a different tool or possibly find an older version of PHPMyAdmin to run as well. Maybe a download mirror hosts an old version somewhere...

Answer (score 39):

I went to /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/common.inc.php and 
comment out this lines:

```
    #if (PMA_MYSQL_INT_VERSION < 50500) {
    #    PMA_fatalError(
    #        __('You should upgrade to %s %s or later.'),
    #        array('MySQL', '5.5.0')
    #    );
    #}
```

and now I can admin my mysql .

UPDATE :

http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#faq1-17 but doesn't explain why

why :

https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/4437/

https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/commit/9112d7c9303b51b7e156cc98fa79ab8824b50e30

Comment: Hi .. appreciate this simple tip, but does anyone know why pma blocked mysql < 5.5? Any incompatibilities or security problems?

Comment: This may work, but if the version is blocked it's not "just because ". This is a sloppy solution.

Answer (score 8):

That particular version of phpMyAdmin is designed for more modern MySQL versions. To resolve the problem, you can either upgrade your MySQL installation or downgrade your phpMyAdmin. Upgrading your MySQL is probably going to involve upgrading to CentOS 7, so you probably aren't ready to do that. Fortunately, the phpMyAdmin team currently continues to support the 4.0.x branch, which requires only MySQL 5 or newer and PHP 5.2 or newer. So you can download 4.0.10.4 (or whatever the current 4.0.x release is) from http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php (where you can also see the listed requirements and anticipated end of life dates).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use PHPMyAdmin then recommend to upgrade your MySQL version to the latest [it is very important for security reasons]. For that, just follow few simple steps:

. Export all your databases and take backup on your local system.
- Upgrade your MySQL version to the latest one..
- Import all your database again from PHPMyAdmin panel.

[Complete tutorials for export/import database from PHPMyAdmin...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NnOE0KWHGkY)

You should not get much problem except password problem for already created database users.  Just reset the password to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the instructions here to set up mysql repo and update your mysql to the latest version:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-repo-excerpt/5.6/en/updating-yum-repo.html

It's better than hacking phpmyadmin down or using an old mysql version.

Answer (score 0):

I did the upgrade, and everything goes to hell, I recommend to totally remove and do a clean mysql install from stratch in order to avoid headaches. Any way for a test environment you may use the hack answer commenting the lines in the "/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/common.inc.php" file or before install mysql, download and install the mysql-repo ad from there proceed to the PMA. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Was getting this error only for one user on my cpanel hosting server.

I changed the `max_questions: max_updates: max_connections: max_user_connections:` values for the user facing the issue from `"1" to "0"`

Post this phpadmin started working.

Answer (score -5):

You're using `5.1` but you should be using `> 5.5`.   You'll need to upgrade or use a different tool like [MySql workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)